# What did Guy say in his fight vs Madara?

Tags: naruto, japanese-language

If you have seen the English subbed version of Naruto Shippuden, then you probably remember the word "Flow!!!" that Might Guy said just before using Night Guy on Madara. My question is, what does he actually say in Japanese? Using Google Translate, I get "nagare" as the Japanese translation of the word "flow". But it sounds like a one-syllable word in the show.

I think this happened in Naruto Shippuden episode 421.

[Here is a clip from YouTube.](https://youtu.be/8y3EIiK28X8?t=254)

Comment: Yes, I had that too maybe he was referring to his super power he attained at that moment

Comment: it would be much better if you could add video clip , link or episode no with the time , so that it will be easier to look what actually Guy said to Madara

Comment: @mirroroftruth : I have added a clip from youtube. You can skip to 4:14. You can find many more clips of guy vs madara on the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Around 1:24 of your clip, Guy says 「積」 *seki*. This is not really a word, per se, but you can take it to "mean" something like "to accumulate" - it is the same character used in the verb 積もる *tsumoru*, which means just that.

Then, at 4:14, the thing he says is 「流」 *ryuu*. Again, this is also not really a word, but it is the same character used in 流れる *nagareru*, which means "to flow".

According to [some random blog I found](http://narutoxjunkie.blog107.fc2.com/blog-entry-1265.html?sp), Guy apparently says the former utterance to build up chakra, and then the latter utterance to release that same chakra. You probably didn't notice, given the prolonged flashback in between the two utterances.

Comment: I remember him saying "charge". And the word "flow" when he says it sounds like "hyu" but I couldn't find this word on the internet. I thought it could be "ryu", since I remember seeing somewhere that ryu means dragon. And sorry I dont understand japanese. I cant understand the blog you posted in the link. It's just that I like to say the name of moves/jutsus in japanese... it sounds cooler that way. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @L16H7 FYI, "dragon" is also _ryuu_, but it's written 龍 or 竜, rather than 流.

Comment: I used google translate on the link, not a good translation though but I think it says about all the names of Guy's jutsu when he opens the gates.